# How to declare a function that is defined further down the code but cannot be shifted upwards?

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax

After clicking `myButton1`, `myButton2` will appear and `myButton1` will be destroyed. Clicking `myButton2` will declare the `askinfo()` command. I would like to include in the `askinfo()` command for `myButton2` to be destroyed, but at the point of declaring `askinfo()`, `myButton2` is not yet declared.

How do I overcome this?

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
root = Tk()

def askinfo():
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Test",
        prompt="What's your Name and Where are you residing currently "
               "tiEg. adam USA California:")
    userinfo = USER_INP.split()

    myLabel = Label(root, text = "Hi "+ userinfo[0] +
                    ", you have been matched with with Timmy, a fellow Singaporean from " +
                    userinfo[1] + "!")
    myLabel.pack()


def myClick1():
    myButton2 = Button(root, text = "Friends", padx=85, pady=50, command = askinfo)

    myButton2.pack()
    myButton1.destroy()


myButton1 = Button(root, text = "Accomodation", padx=50, pady=50, command=myClick1)
myButton1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you saying that part of `askinfo()` should be to destroy `myButton2` in the same way that `myClick1()` destroys `myButton1`?

Comment: Module level functions and variables don't need to be "declared" before something uses them. They just have to exist at the time that use happens. The `askinfo` code can use `myButton2` even if it hasn't been declared (you can't declare things in pytnon, so that's kinda a moot point). Its just that code that creates `myButton2` must run before anyone actually calls `askinfo`. Not sure if this answers the question.

Comment: Calling `myButton2.destroy()` from `askinfo()` will work fine as long as (a global) `myButton2` exists (for the reasons @tdelaney stated) — so you don't have to move it upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one place where a class can help out. In the following code I declared a "widgets" dictionary - a key/value store - in which to keep track of widgets by arbitrary names.

This way you can have more generic methods and so long as you know the flow things will go through you can easily create/destroy widgets all day long.

P.S. This code is written with Python3.x and won't work on Python2.x

```
import sys
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, simpledialog


class RootGui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.widgets = {}
        self.create_button("button_1", "Accomodation", 50, 50, "step_2")

    def step_2(self):
        self.destroy_widget("button_1")
        self.create_button("button_2", "Friends", 85, 50, "step_3")

    def step_3(self):
        self.destroy_widget("button_2")
        name, country, state = self.get_user_info()
        text = (
            f"Hi {name}, you have been matched with Timmy, a fellow "
            f"Singaporean from {state}, {country}!"
        )
        self.create_label("label_1", text)

    def destroy_widget(self, name):
        try:
            self.widgets[name].destroy()
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f"No widget named {name}")
        self.widgets.pop(name, None)

    def create_button(self, name, text, padx, pady, command):
        if name in self.widgets:
            raise ValueError(f"{name} is already a widget name.")
        command = getattr(self, command, None)
        if command is None:
            raise ValueError(f"{command} is not implemented for this GUI class.")
        self.widgets[name] = Button(
            self.root,
            text=text,
            padx=padx,
            pady=pady,
            command=command,
        )
        self.widgets[name].pack()

    def create_label(self, name, text):
        if name in self.widgets:
            raise ValueError(f"{name} is already a widget name.")
        self.widgets[name] = Label(self.root, text=text)
        self.widgets[name].pack()

    def get_user_info(self):
        tries = 0
        normal_prompt = (
            "What's your name and where are you residing currently? "
            "Eg. adam USA California:"
        )
        while True:
            if tries == 0:
                prompt = normal_prompt
            else:
                prompt = (
                    "Please enter all three items - name country state - this is "
                    f"attempt #{tries}. Now, I'll ask again... What's your name and "
                    "where are you residing currently?"
                )
            input_text = simpledialog.askstring(
                title="Location Information",
                prompt=prompt
            )
            if input_text is None:
                sys.exit(1)  # Canceled - not sure what to do here :)
            user_info = input_text.strip().split()

            if len(user_info) != 3:
                tries += 1
                continue
            else:
                name, country, state = user_info
                return (name, country, state)


gui = RootGui()
gui.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to include in the `askinfo()` command for myButton2 to be
> destroyed, but at the point of declaring `askinfo()`, `myButton2` is
> not yet declared.

Use `import tkinter as tk.`

The problem can be fix.

- Move `tk.Button` and `tk.Label` widgets outside of the function.
- In lines 9 and 14, we use the f-string format.
- In line 14, add `myLabel.configure(...` in `askinfo` function
- In line 17, add myButton2.destroy in `askinfo` function.
- In line 22, add `myButton2.configure` in `myClick1` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()

def askinfo():
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Test",
                                      prompt=f"What's your Name and Where are you residing currently\
                                      tiEg. adam USA California:")
    userinfo = USER_INP.split()

    myLabel.configure(text = f"Hi {userinfo[0]}\
                      you have been matched with with Timmy,\
                      a fellow Singaporean from\ {userinfo}!")
    myButton2.destroy()


def myClick1():
     
    myButton2.configure(text = f"Friends")
    myButton2.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)
    myButton1.destroy()


myButton2 = tk.Button(root, padx=85, pady=50, command = askinfo)

myLabel = tk.Label(root)
myLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP)

myButton1 = tk.Button(root, text = f"Accomodation", padx=50, pady=50, command=myClick1)
myButton1.pack(side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot Accomodation:

[image]

Screenshot friend:

[image]

Screenshot for askfor info:

[image]

Screenshot mybutton2 is destroy:

[image]